# Expected value of a product of lognormal distributions; paradox?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, products

Suppose $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are i.i.d. random variables with a lognormal distribution. That is, for $i \in \{1, 2\}$

$$
Y_i = \exp(X_i)
$$

where each $X_i$ is a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Then, by independence:

$$
E[Y_1 Y_2] = E[Y_1]E[Y_2] = \left( \exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)\right)\left( \exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)\right) = \exp\left(2 \mu + \sigma^2\right)$$

At the same time:

$$
E[Y_1 Y_1] = E[Y_1^2] =  \exp\left(2 \mu + \frac{1}{2} 4 \sigma^2\right) = \exp\left(2 \mu + 2 \sigma^2\right) \neq E[Y_1 Y_2]
$$

When I first realized that $E[Y_1 Y_1] \neq E[Y_1 Y_2]$, I thought I had stumbled on a paradox or an impossibility. I'm guessing the reason these values aren't the same is that $Y_1$ is not independent of itself, even if is identically distributed to itself, but it is independent *and* identically distributed to $Y_2$.

Is that all that's going on here? Does anyone have any deeper intuition about what at first glance looked like a paradox to me?

Comment: $E[Z^2]=E[Z]^2$ would imply zero variance, which itself implies that $P(Z=c)=1$ for some $c$.

Comment: Yes, $Y_1$ is not independent of itself (once you know the value of $Y_1$ then you... know the value of $Y_1$, exactly!) and in fact you can show that a random variable is independent of itself iff it is almost surely constant.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.